# Microsoft Intune - get software list from Graph API

Tags: intune, microsoft-graph-intune

In Endpoint Manager, I can list out the software on a test machine and it looks like this:

[image]

Yet when I try to get the same data from the Graph API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/detectedApps
```

That gives me an empty json list:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#deviceManagement/detectedApps",
    "@odata.count": 0,
    "value": []
}
```

I've spent hours now googling for articles and documentation on alternative APIs that might give me the same list, but nothing yet.

So what API should I use to get the list of software on each machine ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it takes a day (or more) for the results to reflect in MS Graph, even though the data appears straight away in endpoint.microsoft.com

That seems very strange, as it's effectively querying different sources between the UI and the API